# Using multiple indicies for arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

I have a simple question about how to use multiple indicies for an array or rec.array. More specifically, I want to isolate the cell(s) in an array which meet multiple stipulations.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.ones(5)
test_rec = test.view(recarray)
test_rec.age = np.array([0,1,2,1,4])
test_rec.sex = np.array([0,1,1,0,0])
```

I want to isolate test_rec where test_rec age is 1 AND test_rec.sex is 1, ie:

```
test_rec[test_rec.age==1 and test_rec.sex==1]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: It appears you are incorrectly creating your recarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use logical_and() or bitwise_and(), and you can use & operator to do bitwise_and():

```
test_rec[(test_rec.age==1) & (test_rec.sex==1)]
```

the brackets is important, because the precedence of & is lower then ==.

Answer (score 1):

```
age_is_one = test_rec.age == 1
sex_is_one = test_rec.sex == 1
age_and_sex = numpy.logical_and(age_is_one, sex_is_one)
indices = numpy.nonzero(age_and_sex)
test_rec[indices]
```

See:

[numpy logical operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations)

[numpy.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)